# Careers won't save when I add website url

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

When I try to add phone, website url, or twitter handle to my StackExchange Careers 2.0 profile, it disappears after I click save. I've tried multiple browsers; I've tried just one field or just another; I can't find any way to make it work.

Comment: I'll look into this shortly.

Comment: @NickLarsen 6-8 Hours later.... :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA yea, yea, I had to make sure it wasn't going to happen again so easily :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be live shortly.  We had some pass through properties on the profile model to the user that were being set implicitly and I deleted the setters after using "find usages" in resharper to "verify" they were not being used.

Comment: It may still be updating, but I just tried it and now the save button gets stuck on "Saving...". Checking the web inspector I get an HTTP reponse code 500 on the following GET:

 http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/cv/updatepersonal/######

Comment: @MattStauffer thanks again for the reply, try that one more time please.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!